# Finding a sufficient condition for primes to be of the form $a^n+b$ with some fixed $n$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be fixed. Given a prime $p$ and integers $a,b$ a necessary condition for $p=a+b^n$ is:
$$p-a\equiv 0 \pmod{b^i}$$
for all $i\le n$. What must one add to these $i$-different conditions to find a sufficienct statement? We can assume $b\ne1$ as $a+1^n$ yields nothing of interest.

Also the statement need not to be computable in finite time (like checking countably many congruences for all naturals greater than $n$)

Any ideas? I'm very much stuck.

Addendum:

To clear things up where I'm coming from consider the following:

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be fixed and $a,b$ integers such that $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

For a $X\subset\mathbb{N}$ we define the characteristic function
\begin{align*}
\Phi_{n,a,b}[X]:X&\longrightarrow \{0;1\}\\
x&\longmapsto \begin{cases}1&x=a+b^n\\0&\text{else}\end{cases}
\end{align*}
If we denote the set of primes by $\mathbb{P}$ my goal is to express $\Phi_{n,a,b}[\mathbb{P}]$ in terms of a (possibly infinite) collection of functions
\begin{align*}
\phi_{m,M}:\mathbb{N}&\longrightarrow \{0;1\}\\
k&\longmapsto \begin{cases}1&k\equiv m \pmod M\\0&\text{else}\end{cases}
\end{align*}
for some $m,M\in\mathbb{N}$ (for simplicity we can choose $0\le m<M$).

It would also be sufficient to find such an expression for $\Phi_{n,a,b}[\mathbb{N}]$, as $\Phi_{n,a,b}[\mathbb{N}]\Big\vert_\mathbb{P}=\Phi_{n,a,b}[\mathbb{P}]$.

Comment: Why don't you simply compute $b^n+a-p$?  Nor do I understand your $i$ conditions...if you just start with $b^n$ you can omit all the others.

Comment: I'm trying to find an expression for the characteristic function $$\Phi_{n,a,b}(p)=\begin{cases}1&p=a+b^n\\0&else\end{cases}$$expressed in terms of $$\phi_{a,N}(n)=\begin{cases}1&n\equiv a\pmod N\\0&else\end{cases}$$That's why $b^n+a-p$ is not helpful. As for your other point: Yep you can omit the first $i-1$ terms, overlooked that. It arose from the idea of $$\prod_{i=1}^n \phi_{a,b^i}(p)$$

Comment: if we knew an easy test. we could find mersenne primes faster...

Answer (score 2):

I very much doubt anyone knows of a singular sufficient condition, that isn't something like the LLR (Lucas-Lehmer-Riesel test, Fermat primes and Mersenne primes would be among the beneficiaries) ,  Here are a few more necessary conditions you missed:

- $a$ and $b$ must be coprime, otherwise $b^n+a$ is divisible by their gcd.
- $a$ must not be congruent to $-1$ mod any of divisors of $b-1$ . Otherwise, by polynomial remainder theorem, the number $p$ is  divisible by the divisors $a$ is congruent to $-1$ in mod.
- $a$ must not be congruent to  $(-1)^{n-1}$ mod any divisors of $b+1$
- $a$ if negative, must not be in absolute value, a power, with exponent a divisor of $n$, unless in doing so, all but one of the algebraic factors turns out to be 1.
- In general $a$ and $b^n$ must not turn out to be additive inverses mod any prime not equal to $p$

There are more, but mostly repeating in a different way.

**Addendum:**

You can do the divisor conditions from $a$ onto $b^n$ as well.

Comment: for example if b is 1 mod 12, one of these tells us a, can't be any but 0,4,6, or 10 mod 12 because all other residues are 1 less than a multiple of a nontrivial divisor of 12: 3,7,11 by 4; 2,5,8 by 3; 1,3,5,7,9,11 by 2; 5,11 by 6 . If it's also 10 mod 11 we have it as 109 mod 132. if n is even a can't be 10 mod 11; if n is odd a can't be 1 mod 11.

Comment: Isn't LLR a prime test, i.e. checks that $a+b^n$ is prime? I see that there is a significant problem to determine wheter a number of such a form is prime, but I'm asking it the other way around: whether the prime (that we already know to be prime) is of this form. This seems much less unreasonable... We could even omit whether the number has to be prime as I want to find the characteristic function $\Phi_{n,a,b}:\mathbb{P}\rightarrow \{0;1\}$ that I mentioned in a comment on my original post. I'm basicially asking when a number $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ is of the form $a+b^n$.

Comment: riesels are of form $kb^n+a,\quad k>1$ usually.

Comment: The answer is: Always, if $a$ can range through all integers.

Comment: I edited my original post to make it a bit more clear what I mean :) I hope this helps understand my concern

Comment: every prime can be stated in this form if a is not restricted.

Comment: don't consider keeping just 12 words the same an edit. my concern is if a is unrestricted in the integers, then this is Always possible to form any of the primes.

Comment: That may be, but $a,b$ and $n$ are fixed. There is no free choice in $a,b$ nor $n$. I just want to find an expression for $\Phi_{n,a,b}[\mathbb{P}]$. (Ok it less of an edit and more of a further explanation, can agree to that)